# How to define schema in CloudKit for a follower relation model

Tags: ios, database-schema, cloudkit

I am working on a CloudKit app for the first time. I have `Channels` and the default `Users`. Now I would like to build a follower relation. What’s the best way to do that? How do I have to create the schema?

I want users to be able to follow channels. I need to query two things:

- Which channels does the user follow?
- How many followers does a channel have?

I tried to add a reference list to the Users model but I get red markers that I can not do queries on that.

I also want to use subscriptions in addition to that, so I can send notifications if the channels update. Can I maybe use just the subscriptions to realise this kind of relation?